# Laravel pass variables to mail template?

Tags: php, html, laravel, email, laravel-5

My problem is that I want to send variables from my EmailController to my mail view and then email to the address. I have tried several things but it didn't work. Hopefully you can help me.

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mail\Email;
use Mail;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
public function sendMail(Request $request)
{

    $option = $request->input('vraag');
    $title = $request->input('onderwerp');
    $body = $request->input('bericht');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $gender = $request->input('aanhef');
    $name = $request->input('naam');

    $data = array(
        'option' => $option,
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => $body,
        'e-mail' => $email,
        'gender' => $gender,
        'name' => $name
    );

    $receiverAddress = 'test@example.com';

           return view('emails.email')->with('option', 'title', 'body', 'e-mail', 'gender', 'name');



}
}
```

I want the request variables to my mail view.
I am getting the error: Undefined variable: data.

My View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Contactformulier</h1>
   <?php
     echo $data['option'];
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setup is correct, but you should access `$option` instead of `$data['option']`.

Bonus: you can pass variables to emails using [`View::share('foo', 'bar')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
 return view('mailview')->with('name', 'email');
```

Comment: I tried this but i am getting the error 'Undefined variable: data'.

Comment: Try accessing using session('name') in the template

Answer (score 0):

you can pass variables to email template as:

```
        Mail::send('emails.templatename', $data, function ($m) {
            $m->from(env('INFO_EMAIL'));
            $m->to(env('PROJECT_EMAIL'), 'admin')->subject('Mail Subject');
        });
```